# Android PdfRenderer - Text Search

Tags: android, kotlin, pdfview, pdfrenderer

I've implemented Pdfrenderer in order to display a pdf?

Is it possible to implement a text search in some way? How can I search the text of the document and rerender with annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've implemented Pdfrenderer in order to display a pdf

`PdfRenderer` is designed for print preview of PDFs created through Android's printing framework. It will not render arbitrary PDFs.

> Is it possible to implement a text search in some way?

There is nothing in `PdfRenderer` to support text search.

> How can I search the text of the document and rerender with annotations?

There is nothing in `PdfRenderer` to support what you are trying to accomplish.